# move rectangle in limited area

Tags: python, pyqt5

There is a roundrect on graphicsscene and i am trying to move but when it goes 'end  of the' any side of screen it goes out of the screen but it should not go outside of the screen it should move like a game callled "SNAKE XENZIA"

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor
import sys


class GraphicsItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)
        self.setFocus()
        self.screenSize = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(0)
        self.screenHeight = self.screenSize.height()
        self.screenWidth = self.screenSize.width()

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0, 0, self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.magenta))
        painter.drawRoundedRect(10, 10, 70, 70, 5, 5)
        # painter.drawEllipse(10, 100, 70, 70)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            self.moveBy(10, 0)
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Left:
            self.moveBy(-10, 0)
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Down:
            self.moveBy(0, 10)
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Up:
            self.moveBy(0, -10)
        self.update()



class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        graphicsitem = GraphicsItem(self)
        self.addItem(graphicsitem)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QColor(10, 155, 79))
        self.screenSize = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(0)
        self.screenHeight = self.screenSize.height()
        self.screenWidth = self.screenSize.width()


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        graphicsscene = GraphicsScene(self)
        self.screenSize = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(0)
        self.screenHeight = self.screenSize.height()
        self.screenWidth = self.screenSize.width()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight)
        self.setScene(graphicsscene)
        self.show()


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        graphicsview = GraphicsView(self)
        self.screenSize = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(0)
        self.screenHeight = self.screenSize.height()
        self.screenWidth = self.screenSize.width()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Graphics View")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor


class GraphicsItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)
        self.setFocus()
        self.screenSize = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(0)
        self.screenHeight = self.screenSize.height()
        self.screenWidth = self.screenSize.width()

    def boundingRect(self):
        self.posX = self.pos().x()                                       # +++
        self.posY = self.pos().y()                                       # +++
        return QRectF(0, 0, self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.magenta))
        painter.drawRoundedRect(10, 10, 70, 70, 5, 5)
        # painter.drawEllipse(10, 100, 70, 70)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
#            self.moveBy(10, 0)
            if self.posX >= 1270: self.moveBy(-1270, 0)                  # +++
            else: self.moveBy(10, 0)                                     # +++
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Left:
#            self.moveBy(-10, 0)
            if self.posX > 0: self.moveBy(-10, 0)                        # +++
            else: self.moveBy(1270, 0)                                   # +++
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Down:
#            self.moveBy(0, 10)
            if self.posY >= 670: self.moveBy(0, -670)                    # +++
            else: self.moveBy(0, 10)                                     # +++
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Up:
#            self.moveBy(0, -10)
            if self.posY > 0: self.moveBy(0, -10)                        # +++
            else: self.moveBy(0, 670)                                    # +++

#        self.update()


class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        graphicsitem = GraphicsItem(self)

        self.addItem(graphicsitem)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QColor(10, 155, 79))
        self.screenSize = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(0)
        self.screenHeight = self.screenSize.height()
        self.screenWidth = self.screenSize.width()


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        graphicsscene = GraphicsScene(self)

        self.screenSize   = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(0)
        self.screenHeight = self.screenSize.height()
        self.screenWidth  = self.screenSize.width()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight)
        self.setScene(graphicsscene)
#        self.show()


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        graphicsview = GraphicsView(self)

        self.screenSize = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(0)
        self.screenHeight = self.screenSize.height()
        self.screenWidth = self.screenSize.width()

        self.initUI()

        self.setFixedSize(self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight)           # +++

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Graphics View")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight)
#        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @DeepakBhargav If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the tour, that is the best way to thank.
  https://stackoverflow.com/tour